# How to display text on gmaps in Jupyter Python Notebook?

Tags: python, google-maps, jupyter-notebook

Background: I'm using the gmaps package in Jupyter Python notebook. I have 2 points A (which is a marker) and B (which is a symbol) which is connected by a line.

Question: I want to somehow display text on this line that represents the distance between A and B. I have already calculated the distance between A and B but cannot display the text on the map. Is there any way to display text on the line?

Comment: I am not sure why you were downvoted, but could you provide some code and what you have tried if applicable. I saw hover text, but not a method to apply text directly. But someone may have a solution so hang in there.

Comment: Thanks Jairus - I found folium package and it had this feature

Comment: Glad you found something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that gmaps doesn't have this feature so I switched to folium package which has labels and popups to display text on hover and clicking the line.